# Why were my comments removed from this question?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

Why were my comments removed from this [question: How to calculate survivability of extremely harsh cold conditions?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/17584/how-to-calculate-survivability-of-extremely-harsh-cold-conditions/17585#17585)?

My comment was along the lline of "'have' and 'die from' are not the same".

Comment: I would like a response from the mod that deleted this.

Comment: 1. They were somewhat abusive. 2. They did not serve the purpose of comments. 3. Comments are not forever, they can be deleted at any time.